# Cascade routers connection - DNS

Tags: networking, dns, cascade

I have connected a network as shown in picture below.

[image]

I can successfully ping location as 8.8.8.8 from client or access directly to web site by IP address, but I can not use domain names.

I assume that problem is in DNS setup on my client, but I'm not sure how to setup it. Anyone with a similar experince ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting a DNS server manually on your client.

network and sharing center > change adapter settings > properties of your LAN adapter > properties of Internet Protocol v4 > use the following dns server addresses (8.8.8.8,4.4.4.4 is google dns) and disable Internet Protocol v6 (otherwise it will search for ipv6 DNS servers)

Comment: The key moment was to disable IPv6.